# How to get everyone to see everyone else's photos in an instagram-like app

Tags: ios, cloud

I am a first time iOS developer trying to build an iOS app from the ground up. It is for a photo-sharing startup that will have similar functionality to Instagram.

I am not sure how to approach the sharing/viewing aspect. Would I use something like Parse or Google cloud storage? It is an iOS only app, if that helps. Given that we are just a startup, a long trial or a cost per GB is fine, but I don't want to be stuck with something expensive if we start getting a lot of photo uploads.

Given that I'm the only developer, I'm hoping for something that doesn't require me to learn too many new technologies. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Parse.com, the API is fairly easy to use. The free plan has a lot of functionality and it scales up well.

Comment: Cool, thanks! When I researched the Parse site before I must have missed their free plan. I like that Parse doesn't autoscale, because I was really worried about getting charged for accidentally over-using!

Answer (score 0):

That's really a tough question. You first want to research each company and weigh the pros and cons with selecting each service. The Google Cloud and Google App Engine (while they do work extremely well together) are going to be a little less "centralized" since they are essentially marketed as separate services. Parse does have that "centralized" feeling since all of their services are designed to work together.

Another nice thing about Parse is that it has build in support for iOS local datastore which means even if your users don't have an internet connection the request will be queued until a connection is made. If you go with a service like the Google Cloud then you would have to implement that on your own or just not have offline functionality.

While Parse looks like a good solution for you, it would be hard for someone to answer your question with a definitive solution as that is up to you exactly how you want your product to work. Just continue to research other solutions as there may be something better and more suited for your exact needs. You may want to build a small prototype on one platform before dedicating all of your development to that platform.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! Good to know about the offline functionality. I am leaning towards Parse, it does seem to encompass a lot of great features and so far seems straightforward.

Comment: Yeah, I would be leaning towards Parse as well in your case. For myself, I just enjoy the Google Cloud platform and find it fun to create on. I tired to keep my answer as impartial as I could.